# Selecting pairs of elements

Tags: sql, postgresql

Well, I have table with a list of computers, and theirs speed and RAM. How can I make a query to retrieve all the pairs of computers with the same speed and RAM as example? I can only show a pair once, so (i,j) instead of (i,j) and (j,i)

something like this:

```
Model | Speed | ram
1006  | 200   | 32
1007  | 200   | 32
1008  | 160   | 16
1009  | 160   | 32
```

So the par will be 1006 and 1007

Comment: What happens if there are three computers with the same speed and ram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a self-join:

```
select c.model, c2.model, c.speed, c.ram
from computers c join
     computers c2
     on c.speed = c2.speed and c.ram = c2.ram and c.model < c2.model;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for it. I did so far getting the pairs but repeating them. How exactly this part: works and c.model < c2.model ?

Comment: That's what restricts it to one of the two pairs. It will return 1006, 1007 but not 1007, 1006